# Can I have enums with parameters?

Tags: java

I have a pre-determined, finite list of values. Each of these values have to be mapped to another value.

Example :

```
AAAAA -> AZER
BBBBB -> BVCX
```

But I also have, depending on some parameter :

```
CCCCC -> CPA1
CCCCC -> CPA2
CCCCC -> CPA3
CCCCC -> CPA4
```

I initially thought of using enums, but how do I factor in the parameter ?

Comment: by adding a variable to your enum, and setting it in it's constructor.

Comment: By what logic `CCCCC` is mapped to different values?

Comment: By reading [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html)

Comment: You can have methods on enums which take parameters.

Comment: Java enums are not union types like in some other languages.

Answer (score 3):

You can add methods to enums, in order to pass the parameters, e.g.

```
enum MyEnum {
  AAAAA {
    @Override String mappedValue(Param parameter) { return "AZER"; }
  },
  BBBBB {
    @Override String mappedValue(Param parameter) { return "BVCX"; }
  },
  CCCCC {
    @Override String mappedValue(Param parameter) {
      if (parameter.equals(something)) {
        return "CPA1";
      } else if (parameter.equals(somethingElse)) {
        return "CPA2";
      } else {
        return "CPA3";
      }
    }
  }
  ;

  abstract String mappedValue(Param parameter);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use constructor like below to map values

```
enum Apple {
  A(10), B(9), C(12), D(15), E(8);

  private int price; // price of each apple 

  // Constructor 
  Apple(int p) {
    price = p;
  }

  int getPrice() {
    return price;
  }
}
```

Comment: That does not allow `CCCCC` to have four different prices "depending on some parameter".